# PHP - bug in time() function when using ZipArchive

Tags: php, wordpress, time, exec, php-ziparchive

I'm using ZipArchive's addEmptyDir/addFile methods to add files to a ZIP file in a loop and measure the current time.
Currently, the relevant part from my code looks like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zip->open($inProgressZipName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
    return array(
        "result" => "error"
    );
}

echo "start time=" . time() . "\n";
foreach ($list as $filePath) {
    echo "loop time=" . time() . "\n";
    $file = utf8_decode($filePath);

    $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($path . '/', '', $file));
}
echo "end time=" . time() . "\n";

$zip->close();
```

I'm getting a very wrong output:

```
start time=1666532175
loop time=1666532175
loop time=1666532175
.
.

loop time=1666532175
loop time=1666532175
end time=1666532175
```

If I change my code to work with **exec** command instead like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zip->open($inProgressZipName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
    return array(
        "result" => "error"
    );
}

echo "start time=" . exec("date +%s") . "\n"; // exec() instead of time()
foreach ($list as $filePath) {
    echo "loop time=" . exec("date +%s") . "\n"; // exec() instead of time()
    $file = utf8_decode($filePath);

    $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($path . '/', '', $file));
}
echo "end time=" . exec("date +%s") . "\n"; // exec() instead of time()

$zip->close();
```

I'm getting a correct input like this:

```
1666532505
loop time=1666532505
loop time=1666532505
.
.
loop time=1666532506
loop time=1666532506
.
.
loop time=1666532606
end time=1666532606
```

As you probably know, I can't use exec because this code will exist on a WordPress plugin, so... what is happening here?

Comment: Use [`microtime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) for benchmarking. My guess, the `exec()` takes a lot longer than a simple `time()` so the reason it look like time is passing when you use `exec()` is that in fact a Lot More Time is passing, where as when you use `time()` you get more done in a milli second

Comment: it's not for benchmarking, it's to stop before the max_execution_time occurs. and microtime() has the same bug also :(

Comment: WHat bug are you talking about

Comment: Maybe you should read this, [`set_time_limit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and slip that into your script if it is runnung long.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem before.
Please try to use PharData instead